# how to add fa fa icons customize menu using wp_nav_menu function?

Tags: menus, icon

how to add fa fa icons customize menu using wp_nav_menu function?

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'menu_id'        => 'footer-menu',
    'menu_class'     => 'quick-link',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way to do this, but I would use jQuery to target the menu items and .addClass(). So, something like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(“.menu-item-one”).addClass(“fa fa-icon”);
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to add your CSS classes to menu.(Here is screenshot)

[image]

[image]